# Disable a resource using count for specific environment with terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to disable a resource for a specific environment in this case its the qa environment, I only want the resource to be created for production and staging.
I have the same terraform code that runs for qa,staging and production via a pipeline.

I have some code used to create an ECS cluster. I don't want it to create for the qa environment.
This is the code that creates the cluster on ECS:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  name = "${terraform.workspace}-main"

  tags = {
    App         = var.app_name
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}

output "main_ecs_id" {
  value = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
}
```

I tried using count to disable the qa environment, and this works:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  count   = terraform.workspace != "qa" ? 1 : 0

  name = "${terraform.workspace}-main"

  tags = {
    App         = var.app_name
    Environment = aws_ecs_cluster.main[count.index].name
  }
}

output "main_ecs_id" {
  value = aws_ecs_cluster.main.*.id
}
```

Only issue is it doesn't work for the environment (production and staging) where I want the resource to create.
When it tries to create the resource with that code on production and staging then I get this error:

```
Error: Self-referential block
on ecs.tf line 8, in resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main":
8:     Environment = aws_ecs_cluster.main[count.index].name
Configuration for aws_ecs_cluster.main may not refer to itself.
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue isn't to do with disabling the resource with count, just that you can't refer to a resource inside itself (provisioners using the [`self` keyword](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#the-self-object) being the exception here but they're extra to the resource).

Instead you'd need to either build the name again or extract the name string into a local:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  count = terraform.workspace != "qa" ? 1 : 0

  name = "${terraform.workspace}-main"

  tags = {
    App         = var.app_name
    Environment = "${terraform.workspace}-main"
  }
}
```

or with a local:

```
locals {
  cluster_name = "${terraform.workspace}-main"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  count = terraform.workspace != "qa" ? 1 : 0

  name = local.cluster_name

  tags = {
    App         = var.app_name
    Environment = local.cluster_name
  }
}
```

The use of locals only allows you to handle things that are known outside of the resource block (eg your string concatenation). If you wanted something that relied on the `count` or `each` in the resource block then you wouldn't be able to use that. There's an [existing issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3267) that covers resource scoped locals as an outstanding feature request.

Comment: Thanks, how would I disable the resource then without self referencing the cluster?

Comment: The same way you already are. The disabling the resource isn't linked at all to the self reference. Do you get an error if you try either of the examples in my answer?

Comment: Thanks that works. Used the first example. For some reason I thought if use count I need to refer to it somewhere else in the resource. Appreciate it

Comment: I just had to add this to the output: ```output "main_ecs_id" {
  value = terraform.workspace != "qa" ? aws_ecs_cluster.main[0].id : null
}```